# How to configure .NET framework on Windows 7

Tags: .net, configuration, windows-7

I don't find the graphic tool to configure my .NET framework on my windows 7.

Thanks
Robie

Comment: question makes no sense as it is....

Comment: .NET framework is an integral part of Windows 7. What do you want to configure?

Comment: I want the equivalent of Mscorcfg.msc for Windows 7 because I don't find it in Administration Tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install .Net Framework SDK to use it for framework 2.0 and later.
For .Net 4.0 it is removed.

See 
[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxsetup/thread/6938f4b8-768c-4d18-b287-b11f92ed9a4a) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bc0cxhc.aspx)